# Cross site publishing and product images

Tags: cross-site-publishing, catalog

I just started setting up a cross site publishing scenario for one of my clients. I have products in a custom lists each item has an ImagUrl (amoung others) which points to an image in a publishing Image list on authoring site. I am going to mark the custom list as Catalog. Do I need to mark the Image list as catalog as well? then do I need to connect an image list on the publishing site to this image list on authoring site? Will the images be imported to the image list on publishing site? What is the best solution in case there is another one? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using external resources in the cross-publishing scenarios it is important to plan ahead access to shared resources - e.g. are all users on the target site have access to source images, etc. - I believe Waldek M.  (http://blog.mastykarz.nl/easier-working-assets-cross-site-publishing/) has very well described this - an option being to effectively use a "shared location" and use that.

Comment: Thank you. I read the post. My question mostly was about if you have many Products then you have to upload images to the publishing sites? Am I right? Is there a way to make the process simpler so that you only upload pages only once?

Comment: You don't actually need to upload "Pages"- you simply define one or more places (e.g. could be standard Lists or if you wish Libraries, such as Pages - most importantly ALWAYS based on a Content Type to which you add a Category column AT LEAST) - could be same or different Site Collections. Then you share those as Catalogs - and on the Target Site Collection you CONSUME (Search does all for you - not COPYING, but rather RETRIEVING). Simply - fill in content in one place, see it in other places.

Comment: I am sorry about my mistake, I meant images not pages. I wanted to find a way to upload images. Beacasue what I have understand images will not be indexed and they must be uploaded to publishing site collections. it seems it is impossible to have an catalog item with its image and expecting the image will be deployed to the publishing sites automatically